# Whenever gem how to work on windows system?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, whenever

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'whenever', '~> 0.9.4',:require => false
```

**config/schedule.rb**

```
every 55.minutes do
 runner "DailyAttendance.fetch_data"
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Cron is a linux application and does not exist on Windows.

Whenever gem does not schedule tasks on it's own, all it does it convert the cron syntax into a human readable form and supply it to the crontab.